# hyperlink onclick is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the image in the same page, whenever user click on a hyper link. Following is my code.When I clicked on any hyper link, it is not calling the function changeImage. Any help please.....

```
<body>
        <h1>Click on any hyper link</h1>

        <div class="left">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="rabbit.jpeg" onclick="changeImage(this); return false;">Rabbit</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="lion.jpeg" onclick="changeImage(this); return false;">Lion</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="tiger.jpeg" onclick="changeImage(this); return false;">Tiger</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="wolf.jpeg" onclick="changeImage(this); return false;">Wolf</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <img src="rabbit.jpeg" id="placeHolder"></img>
        </div>

        <script>
            function changeImage(element){
                var imgValue = element.getAttribute("href");
                var placeHolder = document.getElementbyId("placeHolder");
                placeHolder.setAttribute("src", imgValue);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not calling the function? I put an alert in the function and when I click a link, the alert is firing. I ran it in latest firefox.

Comment: The function is running but the link is being carried out and the page is redirecting to rabbit.jpeg, lion.jpeg etc.

Comment: Ya I got the problem. It is a typo problem. I added alert box at the end of script, because of this typo, it don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your Javascript. Change

`var placeHolder = document.getElementbyId("placeHolder");`

to

`var placeHolder = document.getElementById("placeHolder");`.

```js
function changeImage(element){
                var imgValue = element.getAttribute("data-src");
                var placeHolder = document.getElementById("placeHolder");
                placeHolder.setAttribute("src", imgValue);
            }
```

```css
a:hover{ cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
        <h1>Click on any hyper link</h1>

        <div class="left">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-src="rabbit.jpeg" onclick="changeImage(this); return false;">Rabbit</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-src="lion.jpeg" onclick="changeImage(this); return false;">Lion</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-src="tiger.jpeg" onclick="changeImage(this); return false;">Tiger</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-src="wolf.jpeg" onclick="changeImage(this); return false;">Wolf</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <img src="rabbit.jpeg" id="placeHolder"></img>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ya.. I got the problem. Thanks for the solution.